# Intro to java issue

Tags: java, netbeans-8

very new to the community. I was wondering if someone could explain why my last println creates a compilation error? Thank you.

```
 int beer = 62;
   int pizza = 99;
   int total;
   total = pizza + beer;

   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("5. Sum of two numbers");
   System.out.println(beer " + " pizza " = " total);
```

Comment: You forgot concatenation operator which in Java is `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this :

```
System.out.println(beer + " + " + pizza +  " = "  + total);
```

Note : That we do concatenation in Java using the operator + when atleast one of two operator is of String type.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You should atleast some explanation as well, so in future when newbies read your answer they get it well. (not downvoting).

Comment: You're right @jack-jay, Thanks :)